# .htaccess - handle the case when a user enters www and a subdomain over HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess

Can't get my .htaccess to handle the case when a user enters www and a subdomain over HTTPS.  I am using the .htaccess file from html5 boilerplate
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess

NOT WORKING:
https://www.mysubdomain.mydomain.com --> https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com

WORKING:
http://www.mysubsomain.mydomain.com --> https://mysubsomain.mydomain.com

I've tried multiple answers given from SO but have not had success.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This rule will handle both your `working` and `not working` solutions. So you can relplace your existing rule with the one.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysubdomain\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Panama_Jack, I had the same experience with this solution as I did the one above from @anubhava.  This works on the following cases<br>
* subdomain.domain.com<br>
* www.subdomain.domain.com<br>
* http://subdomain.domain.com<br>
* http://www.subdomain.domain.com<br>
* https://subdomain.domain.com<br>

However I was not able to get it to handle this case...
+ https://www.subdomain.domain.com<br>

Comment: So what's not working. It should be able to handle all cases. Which one is not redirecting?

Comment: @user857276 I see your comment from the other answer. My rule will work for every combination you needed. However you have to have a valid certificate that covers `www.mysubdomain.mydomain.com` or you will get the certificate warning. There **no way** around that. You will either have to purcahse a cert including that or just hope no one tries www in front of your subdomain. However the answer does in fact meet your requirements and would work if the cert was valid.

Comment: Thanks PJ - I voted up your response.  It did work for all of these cases...
[subdomain.domain.com](subdomain.domain.com),
[www.subdomain.domain.com](www.subdomain.domain.com),
[http://subdomain.domain.com](http://subdomain.domain.com),
[http://www.subdomain.domain.com](http://www.subdomain.domain.com),
[https://subdomain.domain.com](https://subdomain.domain.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in place of your existing rule on line 408-413:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s ^www\.([^#]+)#(?:off|on(s)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava - This worked for except when I specified the "https" protocol.  Although this is probably unlikely scenario for someone to enter the URL https://www.subdomain.domain.com - it does get routed to our site - however the user is presented with a security exception "This Connection is Untrusted".  Which is why we wanted to remove the www.

Comment: Thanks anubhava - This worked for except when I used the "https" protocol.  Although this is probably unlikely scenario for someone to enter the URL https://www.subdomain.domain.com - it does get routed to our site and the user is presented with a security exception "This Connection is Untrusted".  Which is why we wanted to remove the www .

Comment: Please note that `"This Connection is Untrusted"` is due to cert negotiation and rewrite rules cannot fix since cert negotiation happens much before `mod_rewrite` is even invoked. (Due to security reasons)

Comment: Thank you for the insight regarding the certificate.  I will have it updated accordingly.  For future reference to others this worked on these cases: subdomain.domain.com,
www.subdomain.domain.com,
[http://subdomain.domain.com](http://subdomain.domain.com),
[http://www.subdomain.domain.com](http://www.subdomain.domain.com),
[https://subdomain.domain.com](https://subdomain.domain.com)